# Unable to set Contact Picture

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow, images

I am trying to set a picture for a contact that is saved on my SIM - I had originally emailed the .jpg to myself from my PC, then downloaded it from the Gmail app. When I go either into Gallery or through My Files and select the picture, select 'More' and then select 'Set as contact picture', the list of contacts comes up but the one I want to associate the picture with is not there - they show up when I use the phone app and look at my normal contact list.

I've got a Galaxy S7 Edge SM-G935F, running Android 6.0.1, kernal version 3.18.14-7538748 dpi@SWDD6418 #1, build MMB29K.G935FXXU1APD1, baseband version G935.FXXU1APD1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you so it directly through the contacts app? When editing a contact there should be an option to add the picture.

Comment: No, it won't let me do it that way either - I can do it on other contacts though, which were transferred over when I upgraded my phone recently - this is the first number I've added to the phone since I got it a month ago.

Comment: Just noticed that you've added them as a SIM contact. I don't think you can add pictures to them, as the sim card doesn't support it. You'll need to add them as a Gmail or phone contact to add things like photos and some other fields.

Comment: Brilliant, just added it as another contact on my Google account and it's work. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Copy the number by editing that contact.
Now create a new contact and choose your existing Google account or Samsung account (if you have a Samsung account logged in, it can be found under drop down menu as pointed in the picture below). Now, as you can see there is **Add picture** option in the picture below, so, add image. :)

Note: SIM card doesn't support any additional options.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1):

SIM contacts do not support additional fields such as a contact photo. You will need to add the contact to Gmail or the phone itself in order to add an image.